# Get the filename behind a friendly url in Java

Tags: java, android, http

How can I know the filename behind a url (not parsing the url and its "/"). For example:

If you visit this url with a browser:

```
http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts
```

it resolves into a **"ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso"**. How can I retrieve this filename in java for download the file with its original name?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The *More Efficient* Way:

You can simply connect to the URL, and then retrieve the URL you are redirected to, by doing the following:

```
URL foo = new URL("http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts");
HttpURLConnection fooConnection = (HttpURLConnection) foo.openConnection();
URL secondFoo = new URL(fooConnection.getHeaderField("Location"));
fooConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
URLConnection fooURL = secondFoo.openConnection();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The line fooConnection.getHeaderField("Location") returns null =(

Comment: Updated to include an example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, did you replace the foo parameter with the URL- Not the location parameter. Leave the location parameter as it is. getHeaderField() gets the Location header from the website. The foo parameter should be the URL. Updated again.

Comment: The getHeaderField("Location") is empty :(

Comment: Try getHeaderField("location")

Comment: This appears to assume only a single redirect; keep in mind that you may be redirected several times. Excellent example, good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `HEAD` request verb to try to discover the data; for this specific file (and using the excellent LWP family of Perl-based HTTP tools) you can find the filename like this:

```
$ HEAD -S 'http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts'
HEAD http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD http://ubuntu.virginmedia.com/releases//precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 22:54:56 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1f83678-2bd4b000-c175d600"
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 735358976
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Last-Modified: Mon, 23 Apr 2012 12:27:04 GMT
Client-Date: Tue, 01 May 2012 22:54:54 GMT
Client-Peer: 194.117.143.72:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
```

The `302` header shows that the object has moved and the stream provides a new URL to retrieve. Most tools will handle this redirect transparently, and if you're hand-writing HTTP, then you also must handle this redirect. In this case, you're lucky that a name is provided -- there may not *be* a file name as the data need not come from a file. But if the context of your tool is relatively restricted, this may not be a problem.